# Showing a GIF or custom Animation. Which one is smoother for Mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, animation

I want to show a waiting icon on mobile app. But wondering which solution is smoother, no laggy? Showing a GIF or create an Animation view?

Answer (score 0):

Both are good but using Custom Animation is better

Answer (score 0):

The smoother one is the ProgressBar and if you are looking for a better design you can use Lottie library, amazing library for animations (including loading...)